# parity of index of subgroup of unit group generated by a Minkowski unit and its conjugates

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field which is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $u$ be a Minkowski unit of $K$ in the (weak) sense as in [AV]. That is, the subgroup $S\subseteq\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ generated by $u$ and its Galois conjugates has maximal rank in $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$, the group of units of $K$.

The usual definition of a Minkowski unit is stronger- usually the index in question is 1 by definition.

I want to know for what class of number fields does there always exist a (weak) Minkowski unit such that this index is odd.

If a (strong) Minkowski unit exists then I'm done. They exist for totally real cyclic fields by [M], but can I weaken these assumptions?

[M] *Marko, František*, [**On the existence of Minkowski units in totally real cyclic fields**](http://dx.doi.org/10.5802/jtnb.486), J. Théor. Nombres Bordx. 17, No. 1, 195-206 (2005). [ZBL1089.11062](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1089.11062)., but can I make fewer assumptions?

[AV] *Akhtari, Shabnam; Vaaler, Jeffrey D.*, [**Minkowski’s theorem on independent conjugate units**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s40879-017-0131-y),  [ZBL06754822](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06754822).